# Counting variable from a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list of matrices

```
data= {{{23,3,4,5,20.5},{24,3,1,0,20.5},{25,3,7,8,20.5},{26,6,5,4,20.5}},{{23,4,5,3,20.4},{24,4,3,5,20.4},{26,4,3,2,20.4},{27,4,5,7,20.4},{28,4,3,2,20.4}},{{23,4,5,3,20.3},{24,4,3,5,20.3},{26,4,3,2,20.3},{27,4,5,7,20.3},{28,4,3,2,20.3},{29,0,0,2,20.3}},{{23,4,5,3,20.2},{24,4,3,5,20.2},{26,4,3,2,20.2},{30,4,5,7,20.2},{29,0,0,2,20.2}}}
```

Each matrix represents a collection of particles at a given time, each row represents a particle with its information `{partice ID, x,y,z, time}`, the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates can be ignored for this problem. Particles can merge together and form a new particle, in which case the `ID` of the more massive particle is retained on the merged particle.

I want to define a variable which counts the total number of NEW particle at each time. So in the given example, at time 20.5, I have 4 particles, at t=20.4 I have 2 new particles emerging, so now I have 6 particles at 20.4, at 20.3 I have 1 new halo emerging, so I have 7 particles, and again at 20.2 I have 1 new halo and so I have 8 particles. I want to have the final result as a table

```
{{20.5,4},{20.4,6},{20.3,7},{20.2,8}}
```

How do I do this? 
Thanks

EDIT : I was imagining, something like the `Tally` function, but finds the distinct particle that arise at each time, so tally compared to the previous group of particles.

EDIT 2: The particle IDs are random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take the IDs of each time-step and accumulate them through the time (but deleting duplicates), then you get the information you want. Therefore, the basic idea is to extract all IDs from each time and then you use `Union` over and over again trough all time-steps

```
FoldList[Union, data[[All, All, 1]]]
(* 
   {{23, 24, 25, 26}, 
    {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28}, 
    {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}, 
    {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}, 
    {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}} 
*)
```

When you look at the lengths of each item, you see that it contains the number you are interested in.

I'm not sure why you chose this kind of representation of your data, because it is not really handy to work with, but your final answer can be extracted by

```
Transpose[
 {
  First /@ data[[All, All, -1]],
  Length /@ FoldList[Union, data[[All, All, 1]]]
  }
 ]
(* {{20.5, 4}, {20.4, 6}, {20.3, 7}, {20.3, 7}, {20.2, 8}} *)
```

Btw, it seems you have a double entry in your `data`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yes I did have a double entry which I have fixed. The simulation that I am using outputs data in this way.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to modify this code a little so that it works even when the data has no particles? data= {{{23,3,4,5,20.5},{24,3,1,0,20.5},{25,3,7,8,20.5},{26,6,5,4,20.5}},{{23,4,5,3,20.4},{24,4,3,5,20.4},{26,4,3,2,20.4},{27,4,5,7,20.4},{28,4,3,2,20.4}},{{23,4,5,3,20.3},{24,4,3,5,20.3},{26,4,3,2,20.3},{27,4,5,7,20.3},{28,4,3,2,20.3},{29,0,0,2,20.3}},{{23,4,5,3,20.2},{24,4,3,5,20.2},{26,4,3,2,20.2},{30,4,5,7,20.2},{29,0,0,2,20.2}},{{}},{{}}}, so the final result is {{20.5, 4}, {20.4, 6}, {20.3, 7}, {20.2, 8},{20.1,8},{20.0,8}} ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another approach combining @SquareOne's observation with `ArrayComponents`:

```
counts = Max /@ ArrayComponents[data[[All, All, 1]]] 
(* {4, 6, 7, 8} *)

times = First /@ data[[All, All, -1]];
Transpose[{times, counts}]
(* {{20.5, 4}, {20.4, 6}, {20.3, 7}, {20.2, 8}} *)
```

Note: Assumed that `0` is not used as a  `particleID`.

Comment: Did not know about `ArrayComponents`.+1

Comment: @SquareOne, thank you for the vote.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you need:

```
With[{a = Merge[Apply[#5 -> #1 &, data, {2}], Union]},
 Thread[{Keys@a, Length /@ FoldList[Union, Values@a]}]]

(* {{20.5, 4}, {20.4, 6}, {20.3, 7}, {20.2, 8}} *)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: @HuShu, it uses Associations which are new in version 10. Perhaps you are using an older version?

Comment: Ah! I see, yes I have version 9.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach. This

```
Max[#[[All, 1]]] & /@ data
```

> {26, 28, 29, 29, 30}

gives you the maximum particle number ID at each successive time (notice as @Halirutan said that you have a double entry (29), but never mind)

Theoretically, by calculating the successive differences between theses elements:

```
Max[#[[All, 1]]] & /@ data // Differences
```

> {2, 1, 0, 1}

you get the number of new particles at each time:

Now, you just need to compute the cumulative sum of this, adding the initial number of particles is which is:

```
Length@First@data
```

> 4

so:

```
newp = FoldList[Plus, Length@First@data, Max[#[[All, 1]]] & /@ data // Differences]
```

> {4, 6, 7, 7, 8}

Finally, each successive time in your data is given by:

```
times = data[[All, 1, -1]]
```

> {20.5, 20.4, 20.3, 20.3, 20.2}

Finally

```
Thread[{times, newp}]
```

> {{20.5, 4}, {20.4, 6}, {20.3, 7}, {20.3, 7}, {20.2, 8}}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like your logic, but I should point out that the halo id in the real data (this was just a mock data) is some random number.

Comment: @HuShu So my approach won't work ;) Please, edit your post to include the info about the random number ID.